# Selecting rows from one table where value and order from another in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  two tables:
post:

```
id    text
1     abc
2     abcd
3     bcd
```

and voting:

```
post_id  vote
2         2
1         5
3         1
1         3
```

I want to show top 10 posts by rating in "votes" table:

```
SELECT * FROM post
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT post_id FROM
        (SELECT SUM(vote) as totalvote, post_id
        FROM voting
        GROUP BY post_id) as table1
    ORDER BY totalvote DESC)
LIMIT 10"
```

but it's order by post id. How can i order it by total votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is what you need:

```
SELECT post.id, post.text FROM post
JOIN voting ON voting.post_id = post.id
GROUP BY post.id
ORDER BY AVG(vote) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

At least I think it would make sense to order by *average* rating. But of course you can order by total points given:

```
SELECT post.id, post.text FROM post
JOIN voting ON voting.post_id = post.id
GROUP BY post.id
ORDER BY SUM(vote) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the top 10 records from `post` by the votes, then use `join` and `group by`:

```
select p.*
from post p join
     voting v
     on p.id = v.post_id
group by p.id
order by count(*) desc
limit 10;
```

To get the actual votes, include `count(*)` in the `select.`